# RegEx: selecting blockquotes and citation similarly to moing moing wiki fails

Tags: .net, regex, parsing

I have a regex that looks like this:

```
(?<bqt>\n\s*(?=\n))|(?<list>(\n|\A)\s+(?<ltype>(?:[-*]|([0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]|[ivxIVX]{1,5})\.))\s)|(?<bq>((\n|\A)\s+|(?<citation>>+)\s*))|(?<bqe>\n\b)
```

The problematic part is this:

```
(?<bq>((\n|\A)\s+|(?<citation>>+)\s*))
```

From below fragments it finds what it superposed to (part 1)

```
>> ... (I said)
> (he replied)

>> a
> b
   a
  b
  .
 .
```

But from this fragment it catches something that it shouldn't (there should be no matches) (part 2):

```
<WikiValid> <WikiNotValid> 
<wiki:WikiValid> 
<wiki:WikiNotValid> 
<nowiki:WikiNotValid>
```

When I change regex to this:

```
(?<bq>((\n|\A)\s+|(?<citation>>+)\s*))
```

Part 2 is ok (no matches), bu in part 1 it doesn't match anything in first two lines. I'm starting to get annoyed. I'm using .NET framework implementation of regex.

- First sample: https://regex101.com/r/iW1pF5/1

  [image: Regular expression visualization]

  [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5whybDKdyHOxD0eu)
- Second example: https://regex101.com/r/gB4uV9/1

  [image: Regular expression visualization]

  [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/R0OkmOrTm0-czni-)

The problem is much more complex, but this part killed me (I must mention, that using python, second part works right)